# Generating random integers

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that can generate 3 random integers from 1 to 100. I thought of using array to store the integers, but I have no idea how I am going to access those 3 random integers. 
I want my code to return something like: 5 92 66. Is there any better way to go about it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nums[100];
    for(int index = 1; index < 101; index++)
    {
        nums[index] = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect output to be something like: 88 17 3.

Comment: What is your question? How to generate random numbers? How to store numbers? How to access "however you stored them" somewhere else? Your use of arrays (indexing 1-100) suggests you don't know C++ very well. You may be better off looking at a text book or an online course first.

Comment: You can only use the 100 locations in `nums` from 0 to 99.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a set S.
Repeat while number of elements in S < 3
    Create random number N with 1 <= N <= 100
    If number N not in S
        Insert N into S
```

Now `S` contains 3 different random numbers. You can create random numbers with [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)